# Azure Dashboard - Agrupa resultado do count

Tags: microsoft-azure

## Hoje

**Tenho o código:**

```
let ["ApplicationSuccess"] = requests
    | where name has "POST /minha-url/" and itemType has "request"
    | where success in ("True")
    | summarize Sucesso = count() by operation_Name;

let ["ApplicationFailure"] = requests
    | where name has "POST /minha-url/" and itemType has "request"
    | where success in ("False")
    | summarize ["Falha Aplicação"] = count() by operation_Name;


ApplicationSuccess
| union ApplicationFailure
| render columnchart with (xtitle="Operação", ytitle="Requisições")
```

**Que retorna:**

Um gráfico com o total de falhas e sucessos das requisições das rotas que sejam POST e que tenham "/minha-url/", isso funciona muito bem quando a rota não tem id´s, quando há id é gerado uma coluna para cada id

## Problema

Preciso agrupar todas estas rotas como se fosse uma, deixando somente total de falhas e total de sucessos, ou seja apenas duas colunas.

## Exemplo

**Hoje:**

| Rotas | Totais |
| --- | --- |
| /minha-url/1 | 10 |
| /minha-url/2 | 12 |
| /minha-url/3 | 20 |

**Resultado esperado:**

| Rota | Total |
| --- | --- |
| /minha-url/* | 42 |

Answer (score 0):

## O "by" agrupa

Testando descobri que o "by" funciona como um "agrupador", então apenas coloquei no "by" o "success" que agruparam as requisições.

**Código:**

```
let ["ApplicationSuccess"] = requests
    | where name has "POST /minha-url/" and itemType has "request"
    | where success in ("True")
    | summarize Sucesso = count() by success;

let ["ApplicationFailure"] = requests
    | where name has "POST /minha-url/" and itemType has "request"
    | where success in ("False")
    | summarize ["Falha Aplicação"] = count() by success;


ApplicationSuccess
| union ApplicationFailure
| render columnchart with (xtitle="Operação", ytitle="Requisições")
```